# Priority Queue with Doubly Linked List Insertion

Tags: c, priority-queue, doubly-linked-list

I am implementing a priority queue waitlist using a doubly linked list. My method creates a new node (priority and student id). Depending on the node priority the method will sort the node into the queue.

```
what I get is                                what I should get

Waitlisted:             109 in 2123      |   Waitlisted:             109 in 2123
Current waitlist:       109              |   Current waitlist:       109
                                         |
Waitlisted:             105 in 2123      |   Waitlisted:             105 in 2123
Current waitlist:       105              |   Current waitlist:       105 109
                                         |
Waitlisted:             108 in 2123      |   Waitlisted:             108 in 2123
Current waitlist:       109 105          |   Current waitlist:       105 108 109
                                         |
Waitlisted:             106 in 2123      |   Waitlisted:             106 in 2123
Current waitlist:       106              |   Current waitlist:       105 106 108 109
                                         |
Waitlisted:             107 in 2123      |   Waitlisted:             107 in 2123
Current waitlist:       109 106          |   Current waitlist:       105 106 107 108 109
```

I am able to insert a new node when the queue is empty on the first loop. Starting from the 2nd run the return values of the queue are wrong.

Code

```
void enqueue( PQNode** ppFront, WaitlistEntry info ){
    /* create a new node to store the info */
    PQNode *temp = (PQNode*)malloc(sizeof(PQNode)); //create a new node to store the info
    temp->info = info;
    temp->pNext = NULL;
    temp->pPrev = NULL;

    /* check if the LL is empty and add the new node to the front if it is */
    if(*ppFront == NULL){
        *ppFront = temp;
        return;
    }

    /* check if the new node should come before the first node in the LL */
    if(temp->info.iPriority > (*ppFront)->info.iPriority){
        temp->pNext = *ppFront;
        (*ppFront)->pPrev = temp;
        *ppFront = temp;
        return;
    }   

    /* walk back through the previous nodes in the LL until the correct insertion point is found */
    /* remember to also check whether the previous node is NULL */
    while((*ppFront)->pNext != NULL && temp->info.iPriority <= (*ppFront)->info.iPriority){
        *ppFront = (*ppFront)->pNext;
    }

    /* insert the new node into the place you found with your loop */
    /* note you may need a special case for when the previous node is NULL */
    if((*ppFront)->pNext == NULL){
        (*ppFront)->pNext = temp;
        temp->pPrev = *ppFront;
        return;
    }
    temp->pPrev = *ppFront;
    temp->pNext = (*ppFront)->pNext;
    (*ppFront)->pNext->pPrev = temp;
    (*ppFront)->pNext = temp;
    return;
}
```

Structs

```
typedef struct{
    int iPriority;          /* Priority of the student to be enrolled */
    int iStudentID;         /* ID of the student */
} WaitlistEntry;

typedef struct PQNode {
    WaitlistEntry info;     /* WaitlistEntry stored in the node (sorted with largest priority first) */
    struct PQNode* pNext;   /* Pointer to next node in the LL */
    struct PQNode* pPrev;   /* Pointer to previous node in the LL */
} PQNode;

typedef struct{
    int iCourseNumber;      /* Course number of the course */
    int* iStudentIDs;       /* Array of IDs of students enrolled in the course */
    int iNumEnrolled;       /* Number of Students currently enrolled in course */
    int iMaxEnrolled;       /* Max number of Students that can enroll in the course */
    PQNode* pFront;         /* Priority queue representing the waitlist for the course */
} Course;
```

I've managed to fix up the code some, but I'm still stuck.

Comment: There is an error in the `enqueue` logic, but it is presumed that there is an error in the display function without relation to it.

Comment: Breaking things into smaller functions can help you debug your logic when things like this occur. For example, when I deal with doubly linked lists, I tend to rely on a set of `connect(prev, current, next)` and `disconnect(prev, next)` functions because the logic can be confusing when dealing with NULL lists, NULL prev/next pointers, etc. Similarly, finding the insertion point can be put into its own function as well. [See this paste](https://pastebin.com/XpbNaG7a) for an example of what I'm talking about. The main functions to look at are `FindPriorityEnd` and `Enqueue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As BLUEPIXY mentioned, the last bit of the function is a bit wrong (//edit you've changed your code in the meantime, I'm referring to your original code). When you go through the list in the `while` block, and then you realize that `curr` is the tail, you fail to check whether you got there because either `temp`s priority is greater than the tail's or you've reached the end of the list and `temp` should become the new tail.

Also, the very last part you are inserting `temp` at the wrong side.

The last part of your code should like this

// edit posting the whole code, I only changed the last bit of your function, and the parameters for `enqueue`, much easier to write test code for this.

```
void print_queue(PQNode *queue)
{
    if(queue == NULL)
    {
        puts("empty queue");
        return;
    }

    for(;;)
    {
        printf("%d (priority %d)", queue->info.iStudentID, queue->info.iPriority);
        queue = queue->pNext;

        if(queue == NULL)
        {
            puts("");
            return;
        }

        printf(" <--> ");
    }
}


void enqueue( PQNode** ppFront, int id, int prio ){
    /* create a new node to store the info */
    PQNode *temp = (PQNode*)malloc(sizeof(PQNode)); //create a new node to store the info
    temp->info.iStudentID = id;
    temp->info.iPriority = prio;
    temp->pNext = NULL;
    temp->pPrev = NULL;
    PQNode *curr = *ppFront;


    /* check if the LL is empty and add the new node to the front if it is */
    if(curr == NULL){
        *ppFront = temp;
        return;
    }

    /* check if the new node should come before the first node in the LL */
    if(temp->info.iPriority > curr->info.iPriority){
        temp->pNext = *ppFront;
        (*ppFront)->pPrev = temp;
        *ppFront = temp;
        return;
    }   

    /* walk back through the previous nodes in the LL until the correct insertion point is found */
    /* remember to also check whether the previous node is NULL */
    while(curr->pNext != NULL && temp->info.iPriority <= curr->info.iPriority){
        curr = curr->pNext;
    }



    /* insert the new node into the place you found with your loop */
    /* note you may need a special case for when the previous node is NULL */
    if(curr->pNext == NULL){
        // we don't know whether the while stopped because it reached the
        // final node or the priority was greater, we have to check it
        if(temp->info.iPriority <= curr->info.iPriority)
        {
            // the priority is smaller, temp should be the tail
            curr->pNext = temp;
            temp->pPrev = curr;
            return;
        } else {
            // the priority is bigger, curr should the the tail
            // this case is handled by the next section
        }
    }

    temp->pPrev = curr->pPrev;
    temp->pNext = curr;
    curr->pPrev->pNext = temp;
    curr->pPrev = temp;
}

int main(void)
{
    PQNode *queue = NULL;

    enqueue(&queue, 109, 10);
    enqueue(&queue, 105, 40);
    enqueue(&queue, 108, 20);
    enqueue(&queue, 110, 30);
    enqueue(&queue, 911, 11);
    enqueue(&queue, 219, 25);

    print_queue(queue);

    return 0;
}
```

I get

```
105 (priority 40) <--> 110 (priority 30) <--> 219 (priority 25) <--> 108 (priority 20) <--> 911 (priority 11) <--> 109 (priority 10)
```

Comment: hmm that makes a lot of sense. I didn't even realize I was placing temp on the wrong side at the end. I tried this out separately and it worked fine, however when I try it in my program the results are different, I guess I have to work on my other functions. At least I now know the errors aren't in here.

Comment: BLUEPIXY mentioned that you may also have an error in your display routine. Make sure that your display routine is working correctly. You can also try using a debugger for this.